# Регулярное выражение // удалить сылку

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой текст:

> Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий позволяет оценить значение соответствующий условий активизации. https://t.co/DJFjdleJcI3 https://t.co/DJEm5ltcjZ

Надо из него удалить вторую ссылку. Всех знаний хватило только на выбор первой ссылки - `(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)`
Язык JavaScript

И возможно может кто то посоветовать хорошую книгу по регулярным выражениям?

Comment: Какой язык программирования?

Comment: JavaScript, должен быть он

Comment: Попробуйте  `s.replace(/(https?:\/\/\S*)\s*https?:\/\/\S*/, '$1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *посоветовать хорошую книгу по регулярным выражениям*

Джеффри Фридл - Регулярные выражения:

---

Шаблон PHP:

[`'~https?://\S+\K\shttps?://\S+~'`](https://regex101.com/r/x8Q82k/2)

Шаблон JS:

[`/(https?:\/\/\S+)\shttps?:\/\/\S+/`](https://regex101.com/r/x8Q82k/3)

Comment: Спасибо, это почти то, что нужно, но теперь узнал, что "flavor" должен быть JacaScript

Comment: @SergeyYugoman я обновил ответ